# Datepicker. No se abre el Calendario en input text

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

Estoy realizando una web de **reservas online**.

Mi duda es la siguiente: Si selecciono una fecha de entrada (check_in), que automáticamente en fecha de salida check_out), se me **bloqueen TODAS las fechas anteriores** debido a que debe ser una fecha superior. **¿Por qué no me sale el Datepicker?**

```js
            $("#check_in").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateStr) {
                var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                if (minDate) { 
                    m.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
                } 
                $('#check_out').datepicker('setDate', minDate).
                datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            }
            });

            $('#check_out').datepicker().on("input click", function(e) {
                console.log("Fecha salida cambiada: ", e.target.value);
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_reservar.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculoNoches.js"></script>
        <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">

            <label for="check_in">Entrada:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">

            <label for="check_out">Salida:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" id="check_out" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

No me muestra ningún error pulsando F12 en consola.

Answer (score 0):

Listo amigo !

Solo tienes que comentar esas lineas en la cual la variable `m?` que no existe le declaras la function `setDate`

```js
$("#check_in").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateStr) {
                var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                //if (minDate) { 
                    //m.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
                //} 
                $('#check_out').datepicker('setDate', minDate).
                datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            }
            });

            $('#check_out').datepicker().on("input click", function(e) {
                console.log("Fecha salida cambiada: ", e.target.value);
            });
            
 function calculoNoches() {
  var checkOut = this.value 
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_reservar.css">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculoNoches.js"></script>
        <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">

            <label for="check_in">Entrada:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">

            <label for="check_out">Salida:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" id="check_out" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Fecha en versión estadounidense

```
 $('#idinput').datepicker({
dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd", // fromato de la fecha
onSelect: function() {
  //funtion al seleccionar un dia
}
});
```

Comment: Gracias. ¿Se podría poner la versión estadounidense? yyyy/mm/dd, por defecto me sale: "mes-dia-año".

Comment: listo amigo espero sea lo que buscas